# Doing a magic trick with limited memory (from a problem solving course)

Tags: group-theory, permutations, contest-math, puzzle

I got the following question in a problem solving course:

> There are four different objects lying on places 1, 2, 3, 4. A magician closes his eyes and someone from the audience comes. He switches pairs of objects 10 times, and each time shouts the places he switched. Then he does a secret switch and doesn't tell the magician the places. Then he switches another 10 times and shouts the places as before. The magician open his eyes, look at the objects and point on one of the objects that participated in the secret switch.
>   The magician has a bad memory, thus he can only remember one number between 1 to 10. How does he do it?

My direction is not to find the secret switch itself, but 2-3 options with a mutual object and choose that object, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: You might want to add the tags "(permutations)" and "(group-theory)" to your question. Seems to me the answer lies in the properties of transpositions.

Comment: Are you sure that he can only remember a number from $1$ to $10$? It might make life easier if it was $1$ to $12$.

Comment: can we use decimals, like $1.0$ and $2.4$?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, I don't think so. A more interesting question is this: can the magician remember a complcated algorithm? It does seem that the problem formulation allows this.

Comment: @zhoraster; good point, +1.234

Comment: Dear all, I know OP and his professor admits he does not know and was mistaken. (Can impossibility be proved?)

@DerekHolt Yes, with 12 we can remember the positions of objects 1 and 2, and then if one of them is not in the right place we know it participated in the secret transposition.
Dear zhoraster and Jon, I think of the algorithm as 20 functions generating a number in $\{1,...,10\}$ given the current transposition and the previous function's result, followed by a function into $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: I would interpret things as follows. The algorithm and all information required to convert an ordered pair into a number from $1-12$ can be stored in read-only memory, which is available at all times. The restriction on remembering a number is referring to a number that is changing throughout the process.

Comment: The magician remembers the number of switches performed by the audience member, and peeks after the tenth switch. (More seriously, can the magician remember the step number in addition to the number from 1 to 10?)

Comment: I don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a reasonably simple way to do it, remembering an integer between $-4$ and $4$ . It's really a modulus between $1$ and $4$, and a sign, that must be tracked independently; it’s actually easier than remembering a number between $1$ and $10$ (though if the magician just can’t remember negative numbers, he can substitute $5,6,7,8$ for $-1,-2,-3,-4$).

The modulus is the position where object $1$ should be, disregarding the secret switch. So whenever the magician hears a pair of numbers and one of them is the modulus he has in mind, he switches his modulus to the other number. He has $2$ in mind and hears $2,4$? He concentrates on $4$. He has $3$ in mind and hears $1,3$? He concentrates on $1$. He has $4$ in mind and hears $1,3$? He keeps concentrating on $4$.

The sign is switched whenever the magician hears and odd-even pair, otherwise it is left unswitched. He has $-1$ in mind and hears $2,3$? He concentrates on $1$. He has $-4$ in mind and hears $2,4$? He concentrates on $-2$. (He does not switch sign, but he does switch modulus!)

The magician starts with the number $1$ in mind and follows the two rules above, tracking the (alleged) position of object $1$ in the modulus, and flipping the sign when hearing odd-even switches. At the end of the game:

1. He checks the position he has in mind. If he does not see object $1$, he points to object $1$.
2. Otherwise, he asks himself whether neither or both of objects $1$ and $3$ are in an odd position. If the answer and the sign agree, i.e. they are both positive or both negative, he points to object $2$.
3. Othewise, he points to object $3$.

Let's prove it works. First of all, it's pretty obvious that object $1$ is where the magician looks for it if and only if it was left alone during the secret switch. If it is not, the magician can point to object $1$.

Otherwise, consider the parity of the number of odd-even switches necessary to bring every object to the starting position: it is $0$ if and only if both or neither $1$ and $3$ are in an odd position (including at the beginning of the game), and obviously changes if and only if there’s an odd-even switch. So both the answer to the question “are both or neither ...”, and the sign of the number the magician remembers, are positive or negative depending on whether there were an even or an odd number of parity switches respectively in the room and in the “called out” switches; the secret switch was an odd-even switch if and only if they disagree. If they agree, the switch must have been between between $2$ and $4$, since it did not involve $1$, so the magician can point to $2$. If they agree, the switch must have involved $3$ since, again, it did not involve $1$ - so the magician can point to $3$.

Comment: so if do the four following switches : $(1,2), (2,3), (1,2), (1,3)$, we will have done nothing at all, but the magician will have switched his sign. I don't think this can work.

Comment: @mercio try to give a sequence of 21 switches that makes the scheme above fail then!

Comment: $(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)$ for the first ten, then secretly switch $(2,4)$, then $(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)(1,3)$ for the last ten. There are three odd-even pairs and $1$ ends up on $1$ so the magician ends up on $-1$. He sees that $3$ is in an odd position, which he believes is impossible so he declares that $3$ has been switched.

Comment: "the parity of the number of odd-even switches necessary to bring every object to the starting position" is meaningless, because an odd number of odd-even switches can do the identity transofrmation ($(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)(1,3)$)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a summary than an answer, because the answer might be that it is impossible.

We shall first assume that the magician can only remember integers but otherwise has a finely tuned mind.

We can recall that transpositions are generally non-commutative.

To store the information the magician needs, I can see three options, none of which use the full quota of $10$:

- the magician remembers the permutation of $123$
- the magician remembers the position of $4$ and the parity of $123$
- the magician remembers the last digit and the parity of the remaining digits

Depending on how clever the magician is, he/she calculates each of the possible $24$ outcomes at the halfway point. This might not be necessary however, as they only are required to identify one of the two objects affected by the secret switch.

So we need to determine whether or not this is possible.

Comment: Sadly, none of these options work (if I'm understanding the problem correctly). 1) There is no way to keep track of permutation of $123$ because after another switch you wouldn't know which numbers were switched, only which places (and magician forgot about placement of $4$ and hence of other placements). 3) is same as 1), let's say first switch was $1234 \to 2134$. Now magician remembers $(4,-1)$ and can't deduce anything after next switch. Number 2) can be tracked, but is no tell because parity of $123$ is uniquely determined by position of $4$ at the end.